# If a college/ university made false claims on its website, should you still consider studying there?

Tags: application

The school I'm taking about here is regionally accredited. The problem is, on its website, it falsely claims to be a member of two different international academic associations. Should I look for a different school **just because of this**?

*PS: I asked these academic associations through email if the school is any way related to or affiliated with them at any time. They gave me a negative reply.*

Comment: What does regionally accredited mean?  What country?

Comment: Anyone can "accredit" a school.  I could "accredit" a school and so could you.  The question is *by what agency* is this school accredited.  If the school is in the US, is it accredited by some agency recognized by the Department of Education?  For those see http://www2.ed.gov/admins/finaid/accred/accreditation_pg6.html

Comment: In the US, "regionally accredited" means accredited by one of the six major accrediting agencies in different regions of the US such as the Higher Learning Commission (which covers the north central region of the US.)  In addition to regional accreditation, the US Department of Education recognizes a number of other national accrediting bodies.  Regional accreditiation is generally considered to be more credible than accreditation by one of these other bodies.

Comment: I've voted to close because it's simply impossible to answer the question without more detail.

Comment: What kind of associations are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure this isn't a mistake or misunderstanding from either the university or the association?

I would recommend contacting the department or university. I try to give people the benefit of the doubt with this type of thing but are you sure this is a reputable school? *Accreditation* is a vague thing and varies wildly in how it is regulated and who accredits it, especially across different countries.

I'm a little surprised that you contacted the association directly. I myself never pay attention to professional associations and don't know anyone who does (at least not enough to investigate the claim).

But again, if this is important to you, I would recommend giving the university a chance to clarify by contacting them. You must remember, the people making the website or handling the accreditations most likely aren't the professors teaching the courses. I would also recommend looking into the reputation of this university more if this is indeed true.

**EDIT:** Many diploma mills/for-profit schools are "accredited" but that doesn't mean they are *reputable*, so beware.

Comment: All degrees offered by this school are accredited nationwide. That said, this school is not that "popular", because its programs were designed primarily for continuing and working students.

Comment: @user50284 Ah, this sounds like a for-profit school then. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This absolutely, but if there isn't any mistake then I wouldn't have a thing to do with them.